# The operating system of the container does not match

Tags: docker-for-windows

I have created a Windows Server 2016 VM, build 15063.2.

I installed Docker EE according to these [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/docker-ee-for-windows/install/).

I can pull images and list them.  But I cannot run them.

I tried running microsoft/windowsservercore using this command.

docker run -it microsoft/windowsservercore cmd

It fails saying the version of the OS doesn't match.   Full error output is  below.

> docker: Error response from daemon: container
>   266a8f9f77f7ee57efb41ecd74001721b57fbbf1fc85150fd5156627782b6f61
>   encountered an error during CreateContainer: failure in a Windows
>   system call: The operating system of the container does not match the
>   operating system of the host. (0xc0370101) extra info:
>   {"SystemType":"Container","Name":"266a8f9f77f7ee57efb41ecd74001721b57fbbf1fc85150fd5156627782b6f61","Owner":"docker","IsDummy":false,"VolumePath":"\\?\Volume{8adf7e25-dc21-4bb9-8aaf-80408b5d5085}","IgnoreFlushesDuringBoot":true,"LayerFolderPath":"C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\266a8f9f77f7ee57efb41ecd74001721b57fbbf1fc85150fd5156627782b6f61","Layers":[{"ID":"9ca74b81-1d43-5ae3-b82e-4c584e5ebba7","Path":"C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\1e0c3f8d0cd7905b72efc4b4114c33b4585623e82a3d661636c68a5637a213d2"},{"ID":"86613523-d1d5-5b5b-8889-fc0c33a7d7ab","Path":"C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter\31578f2c995a3891bb3af19de88efff45dbec9f9bdc6067c133abcf05a451171"}],"HostName":"266a8f9f77f7","MappedDirectories":[],"HvPartition":false,"EndpointList":["43f9f400-ce4f-48e9-89a1-b3b804285e61"],"Servicing":false,"AllowUnqualifiedDNSQuery":true}.

**How do I figure the correct version of the host OS to use?**

Comment: You minor version of OS shall match minor version of container. Make sure to install all latest updates/patches to Windows 2016

Comment: I didn't "switch".  I'm running WS2016 as a VM.  Installing Docker installed the "Containers" windows feature.  So I'm assuming I'm running Docker engine as Docker Containers instead of VM isolated containers.  I'm not sure I could even run VM isolated from within a VM.

Comment: Thanks Gregory, I'll try that.

Comment: I think my problem is that I'm running 15063 (RS2) when the docker container image is 14393 (RS1).   I'll try installing WS2016 build 14393.

Comment: You can also run older version of Base container as well